# Overidding dj-rest-auth Registration Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dj-rest-auth

I am trying to override the register serializer, I want to add a name field but the default view still shows

this is my configuration in settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer'
}
```

my url looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
  ]
```

while my serializer

```
from dj_rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer

class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = [
            'name',
            'email' 
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `REST_AUTH` instead of `REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS`?

```
REST_AUTH = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer'
}
```

Comment: yeah, this is what i later used. thanks